# how to add a foreign key referance in AspNetUsers in mvc5

Tags: c#

Please can anyone help me! 
I have a Model class named: Student.
Now i need to save a user with "StudentID". "StudentID" will be saved in user table as foreign key.
here is my Student class

```
public class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstMidName { get; set; }
    public int? DepID { get; set; }
    public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DepID")]
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }

}
```

and my identity model is

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{

}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {

    }
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

so how can i add "studentID" into user table as foreign key.

Answer (score -1):

In case you just want to use the StudenID as a foreign key in a different table, you can do it like this e.g

```
 public class Employee
  {
    [Key]
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual EmployeeDetail EmployeeDetail { get; set; }
  }

public class EmployeeDetail
  {
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Employee")]
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string Adress { get; set; }

    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
  }
```

In case you are talking about the actual User table created by Asp.Net Identity, then you can simply extend and customize the User table:

http://typecastexception.com/post/2014/06/22/ASPNET-Identity-20-Customizing-Users-and-Roles.aspx

Comment: Sorry! i think u did not get it. How to use student id in user table as foreign key?

Comment: By "User table" are you referring to the Asp.Net Identity table Users?

Comment: Sorry I can't help you if you do not elaborate.